# A simple Common-Lisp cat

Tags: common-lisp

How do I translate this into Common Lisp?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

I looked in *ANSI Common Lisp* and duckduckwent a bit, but
couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibile equivalent is:

```
(loop for c = (read-char t nil) 
      while c 
      do (write-char c))
```

See [the example](https://tio.run/##JczBDYAgDAXQVf4RDrqBG7gEgRqbFEsKhvErieeXvCzcm3sQ1YZLDRkHglEqW76TYeBhiZg3Cy0rijCNB/2aY3Q/1aiCW3/rcllH54FUaewf).